# How Dictionary Apps provide feature of clicking every word?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Good Day Team,

I would like to know **how user is able to click every word in the dictionary apps** and it jumps to another screen where the meaning of the word is mentioned. I want do it using Android Jetpack Compose (Kotlin). 1 way is creating separate text box for every word but that would be unwise for larger sentences. There must be some easier way.

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be using `ClickableText` to get index of character touched in text. Then you need to apply some sort of algorithm to detect words. I would put ranges startIndex..endIndex as key and word as value to a map and check if touch index in any of these ranges. Probably there are better options for detecting from selected index. This is only a suggestion.

```
   // Clickable text returns position of text that is clicked in onClick callback
    ClickableText(
        modifier = modifier,
        text = annotatedString,
        onClick = {
          // Logic to find words from character indx
        }
    )
```